# Creating <div containers the same height

Tags: html, css

I'm creating my first web page and I have 3 boxes with an image and text as contet. How do I make the boxes the same height regardless of the content?

New to css etc so please help.

I have tried padding, margin etc but nothing. My code is as follows:

```
     <!------------------------------   Three Small Span Boxes  --------------------------->
<div class="container-full-width" id="boxes_lite_section">
    <div class="container" >
        <div class="container-fluid" >

            <!-- Start of markup for boxes lite element -->
            <div id="widget_boxes_container" class="row-fluid" >
                <div class="boxes">
                    <div class="box span4">
                        <p>
                            ***
                        </p>
                        <a  class="box-link">
                            <img class="box-image" src=".jpg" />
                        </a>
                        <p align="justify" style="margin-top:20px">
                            content here funding.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <!--end box1-->

                    <div class="box span4">
                        <p>
                            ***
                        </p>
                        <a  class="box-link">
                            <img class="box-image" src=".jpg" />
                        </a>
                        <p align="justify" style="margin-top:20px">
                           content here
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <!--end box2-->

                    <div class="box span4">
                        <p>
                            ***
                        </p>
                        <a class="box-link">
                            <img class="box-image" src=".jpg" />
                        </a>
                        <p align="justify">
                            content here
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <!--end box3-->
                </div>
                <!-- end boxes -->
            </div><!-- end row-fluid -->
            <!-- End of markup for boxes lite element -->
        </div>
        <!-- .container-fluid-->
    </div>
    <!-- .container -->
</div>
<!-----------------------------  End Three Small Span Boxes  ------------------------->
```

Comment: try `div.box {height:/*your proper height*/}`

Comment: if it's possible that the content was taller than box height, set `overflow: auto` or `overflow: scroll` for div.box... It's result have to be like your code in your question.

Comment: @Kiyarash hey thanks. Stupid question again but where would I put the code for 'div.box{height: etc mentioned above. What are the {} for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set the `height` for an element, it will be shown with this regardless of the content.
***`BUT`*** if the content become taller than height, the result may be very ugly.
so, it's better to set `overflow:auto` in your case, that will save the box height when content is taller...

```
div.box {
  width: 350px; /*for example*/
  height:300px; /*for example*/
  background: blue; /*for example*/
  color:white; /*for example*/
  overflow:auto; /*for example*/
  border:4px solid red; /*for example*/
}
```

[You can see result Here](http://jsbin.com/bewod/1/edit) and you can find out your last question you mentioned in comment...

If you want to hide overflow, try `overflow:hidden` instead...

Comment: I think OP is asking for dynamic height here like in Stormtroopr's answer

Comment: @Kiyarash this fixes the height of the content, which is the opposite of what the OP asked for.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr he asked `regardless of the content?`... overflow made it... didn't?

Comment: No, because the height of the box isn't tied to the content its tied to an arbitrary height. CSS Tables are a much better solution now days.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr it's your Idea and I respect that, but it's very basic example, so I don't think like you...

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with variable height you can use CSS tables to render your `div`s.

```
div.boxes { display:table-row;  }
div.box   { display:table-cell; }
```

[This jsfiddle should give you an indication of what it will look like with your layout.](http://jsfiddle.net/pTAJP/)

[Practically every major browser supports CSS tables now](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-table), so feel free to use them when necessary. Fixed heights are ok, but can cause issues when your content grows beyond your original expected size.